# This solution contains resources scoped for a Web application and must be deployed to one or more Web applications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell

Hi don't mark this question as duplicate or  replicated. Because I have googled a lot for this error and I have found solutions which can work my Install-SPSolution command. However what I am looking is. Error says ***solution contains resources scoped for a Web application***

***My question is :***  I need to find which are the resources that I am missing to deploy?

***My Progress***

```
$w = Get-SPSolution "SI.Sharepoint.FeedWebpart.wsp"
$w.ContainsWebApplicationResource
```

returns me ***True***

Now I need to find what are the resource files it is talking about? which are those resources that I am missing to Add/deploy? Is there any power shell script that I can look at as what are the resource files?

Answer (score 0):

I went through my code and I was able to identify by myself.

***The solution to this is.*** 
 *

> I had a safecontrol declared in my .spdata file which was looking for
>   web.config file to register but couldn't find web.config file. Nevertheless I commented the safecontrol tag from the .spdata file and the installation started working. 
>   *

Looks very silly but more helpful. Happy coding :)